# Evaluating $\oint\frac{dw}{(w-w_+)(w-w_-)} $ over the unit circle, where $w_\pm=z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}$ and $z\in\Bbb{C}$ with $|w_+|\neq|w_-|$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

The following problem arises in E. N. Economou's ''Green's Functions in Quantum Physics'', 3e.

> Evaluate the following integral over the unit circle
> $$
> \oint\frac{dw}{(w-w_+)(w-w_-)}
> $$
> where
> $w_\pm = z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}$,
> and $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|w_+|\ne|w_-|$.

Supposing $w_+$ is the root inside the unit circle, the answer is

$$
\frac{1}{w_+-w_-}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z^2-1}}
$$

I'm fine up to this part. Economou then says

> where the square root [in the answer above] is the one that has the same sign of the imaginary part as the sign of $\mbox{Im}\,z$.

Could someone explain what justifies this choice of the principal branch? Forgive me if this is an obvious question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ and $s = u+iv$ be a square root of $z^2-1$. ($x, y, u, v$ all real numbers). Then
$$
\begin{align}
 u^2-v^2 &= x^2-y^2-1 \, ,\\
 2uv &= 2xy \, .
\end{align} 
$$
$w_+ = z+s$ and $w_- = w-s$ are the roots of $w^2-2zw+1=0$, so that their product is equal to one. It is also assumed that $|z+s| \ne |z-s|$, which means that exactly one of the roots has modulus less than one. Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
 |w_+| < 1 &\iff |z+s| ^2 < |z-s|^2 \\
&\iff 0 < \operatorname{Re} (z \bar s) \\
& \iff xu + yv > 0 \, .
\end{align}
$$

If $y \ne 0$ then $x=uv/y$ and
$$
xu + yv = \frac vy (u^2 + y^2)
$$
is positive if and only if $v/y$ is positive, that is if $v$ has the same sign as $y$.

And if $y=0$ then necessaily $v=0$ because otherwise $2uv = 2xy=0$ would imply $u = 0$ and then $xu + yv = 0$.

So $|w_+| < 1$ exactly if $s = \sqrt{z^2-1}$ where the square root is chosen such that its imaginary part and the imaginary part of $z$ are both zero or have the same sign.